# Streaming data into bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to stream  my data into BigQuery one record at a time by using the `tabledata().insertAll()` method.

I have already created a project with one dataset. So I dispose the following informations:

ProjectID and DatasetID.

The IDE on which I am working is Eclipse

My question is: What should I download (libraries,package...) allowing me to dispose all the necessary to begin using all classes and appropriate methodes?

In other words, what remain to access the Google BigQuery API, allowing objects to be instanciated and methods to be invoqued in Java?

Answer (score 2):

You need Google API Java Client libraries: 
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/

And here is the BigQuery section of it: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/bigquery/v2